# Excel 2016 VBA Display every nth Data Label on Chart

Tags: excel, charts, formula, label

I have a line chart that displays the revenue of multiple airlines, throughout the period of 2011 to 2016 - with data points plotted quarterly (Q1-Q4, for each year) on the X-axis

I would like to only show the data labels (on the chart) for Q4 of each year, for each airline. I would like to do this and keep the axis as is.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated,

Thank you!
(I have Excel 2016)

Comment: Why do you added `vba` tag? Did you tried to put all the other values in 0 except of Q4? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited - because I've seen responses to similar questions that have used excel-vba to provide a solution. However, have not been able to implement these myself. Thanks for your response

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 1):

Your question didn't express clearly if you want to add the labels by means of a VBA macro.
I suggest to do following:

```
Dim sData as Series
For i = 1 to sData.Points.Count Step 4
 sData.Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
Next i
```

Note that if there is not value for the Point i in the series, the label seems not to be displayed. It took a while to find out why a label was not added to the chart. To detect this case, I wrote following test:

```
If sData.Points(i).HasDataLabel Then
 If Len(sData.Points(i).DataLabel.Text) = 0 Then
  ...
 End If
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching a little in the web (around 3 minutes, that maybe you should spend the same time) found this article:

> http://www.cs.mun.ca/~n39smm/Excel/Data%20Label.pdf

This is the resume, but I suggest to view the document because have a lot of graphics.

1. Click on the bar you want to labeled twice before Add Data Labels.
2. Click on the label, then right click and select Format Data Labels.
3. Check the Category Name and uncheck Value.

A little research before asking can save you a lot of time.